# How should appropriate Django session template look like?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, session, django-rest-framework

I'm not sure I am using Django session in an appropriate way. To login I use this view and URL:

`url(r'^login/$', views.my_login)`

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

@api_view(['POST'])
def my_login(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
      if user.is_active:
        request.session.set_expiry(86400)            
        login(request, user)
```

In every method that requires authentication I use `if request.user.is_authenticated()` or `@login_required`

If this is a good method how can I use both `@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])` and `@login_require`?

It seems to me that it isn't a good solution:

```
@login_require
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def my_func(request):
    #...
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using django-rest-framework i would suggest using their default way of authentication.

Use @authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication))

[drf setting-the-authentication-scheme](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme)